# Can I use a function to either import or install a module

Tags: python, function, python-import

I am running Windows 7, Python 2.7, Anaconda 4.0.0:

Here is what I want to do. I want to take this code and put it in a function.

```
try:
    import easygui
except ImportError:
    from os import system
    system('pip install easyqui')
    import easygui
else:
    pass
```

This is what I have come up with but I am not able to get it to work.

```
def install(mypack):
    try:
        import mypack
    except ImportError:
        from os import system
        system('pip install ' + str(mypack))
        import mypack
    else:
        pass
install('easygui')
```

The error I get is "ImportError: No module named mypack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` statement takes the module name literally and not just as a reference to some other object. So `import mypack` does not translate to `import easygui`, but *import module mypack*

Instead, you should use the builtin [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) which takes a name/string:

```
__import__(mypack)
```

Comment: Better to use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)?